# how and where to add a more specific join of two entity tables

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework

I am trying to build what i thought to be an easy directory for our company. I'm not a web developer, I am a standalone application developer, so my knowledge of ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework is limited.

I followed some instructions I found online and created the entities (2 tables) in an older application, the SQL statements used to get the list of employees utilizes a left outer join and 3 where parameters. I'm assuming I have to use LINQ in the `model.Context.vb` file?

I also see `Details` methods in the controller but it creates an instance of this context file so I assume that is where I need to combine the two entities and then access the refined list through the controller, is this about right? How and where would I write the LINQ statement if that's what I even need to do?

[image: Context.vb diagram][image: Context code]

This is the controller:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports MillDirectory

Namespace Controllers
Public Class tblUsersController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    Private db As New HDDataEntities

    ' GET: tblUsers
    Function Index() As ActionResult
        Return View(db.tblUsers.ToList())
    End Function

    ' GET: tblUsers/Details/5
    Function Details(ByVal id As String) As ActionResult
        If IsNothing(id) Then
            Return New HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        End If
        Dim tblUser As tblUser = db.tblUsers.Find(id)
        If IsNothing(tblUser) Then
            Return HttpNotFound()
        End If
        Return View(tblUser)
    End Function

    ' GET: tblUsers/Create
    Function Create() As ActionResult
        Return View()
    End Function

    ' POST: tblUsers/Create
    'To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    'more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    <HttpPost()>
    <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
    Function Create(<Bind(Include:="USLanID,USAS400ID,USVaxID,USLName,USFname,USDepartment,USPhoneNumber,USFaxNumber,USExtension,USPagerNumber,USSupervisor,USPhoneAreaCode,USPagerAreaCode,USFaxAreaCode,USHelpDeskFlag,USAvailable,USAvailableDate,USEmail,USDomain,USInactive,KICKUser,KICKMinutes,USNewTicketNotify,USNAME,USClosedTicketnotify,USCellAreaCode,USCellPhoneNumber,USAllowedToPage,USLocation,USHomeArea,USHomePhone,USExcludeHomePhone,USEmpNum,USCellTxtMsgAddress,USHireDate,USTrackVac,USIncludeinCellDownload,USRecoveryMsg,USPowerMsg,USPMBreakMsg,USProdRPT,USStockRPT,USPagingType,USPicturePath,USTest,USPMBreakMins,USPMBreakNum,USmsgPCName")> ByVal tblUser As tblUser) As ActionResult
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            db.tblUsers.Add(tblUser)
            db.SaveChanges()
            Return RedirectToAction("Index")
        End If
        Return View(tblUser)
    End Function

    ' GET: tblUsers/Edit/5
    Function Edit(ByVal id As String) As ActionResult
        If IsNothing(id) Then
            Return New HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        End If
        Dim tblUser As tblUser = db.tblUsers.Find(id)
        If IsNothing(tblUser) Then
            Return HttpNotFound()
        End If
        Return View(tblUser)
    End Function

    ' POST: tblUsers/Edit/5
    'To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    'more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    <HttpPost()>
    <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
    Function Edit(<Bind(Include:="USLanID,USAS400ID,USVaxID,USLName,USFname,USDepartment,USPhoneNumber,USFaxNumber,USExtension,USPagerNumber,USSupervisor,USPhoneAreaCode,USPagerAreaCode,USFaxAreaCode,USHelpDeskFlag,USAvailable,USAvailableDate,USEmail,USDomain,USInactive,KICKUser,KICKMinutes,USNewTicketNotify,USNAME,USClosedTicketnotify,USCellAreaCode,USCellPhoneNumber,USAllowedToPage,USLocation,USHomeArea,USHomePhone,USExcludeHomePhone,USEmpNum,USCellTxtMsgAddress,USHireDate,USTrackVac,USIncludeinCellDownload,USRecoveryMsg,USPowerMsg,USPMBreakMsg,USProdRPT,USStockRPT,USPagingType,USPicturePath,USTest,USPMBreakMins,USPMBreakNum,USmsgPCName")> ByVal tblUser As tblUser) As ActionResult
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            db.Entry(tblUser).State = EntityState.Modified
            db.SaveChanges()
            Return RedirectToAction("Index")
        End If
        Return View(tblUser)
    End Function

    ' GET: tblUsers/Delete/5
    Function Delete(ByVal id As String) As ActionResult
        If IsNothing(id) Then
            Return New HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        End If
        Dim tblUser As tblUser = db.tblUsers.Find(id)
        If IsNothing(tblUser) Then
            Return HttpNotFound()
        End If
        Return View(tblUser)
    End Function

    ' POST: tblUsers/Delete/5
    <HttpPost()>
    <ActionName("Delete")>
    <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
    Function DeleteConfirmed(ByVal id As String) As ActionResult
        Dim tblUser As tblUser = db.tblUsers.Find(id)
        db.tblUsers.Remove(tblUser)
        db.SaveChanges()
        Return RedirectToAction("Index")
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If (disposing) Then
            db.Dispose()
        End If
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub
End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1: You can pull the result set by adding this in the Controller. I have edited the Index action:

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
    var query = from u in db.tblUser
                join p in db.tblUserPermission on u.UserID equals p.UserID
                where u.YourProperty == YourCondition 
                into gj
                from x in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new { 
                 UserID = u.UsergroupID,
                 UserPermission = p.UserPermission               
                };
    Return View(query)
End Function
```

Method 2:

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
    Return View(db.UserDbSet.UserPermissionList.Where(w => w.YourProperty == 
                w.YourFirstCond && w.YourAnotherProp == w.YourSecondCond).ToList())        
End Function
```

Assuming your DbSet for the left table is UserDbSet.
Before that, you would need to change the Models(Entities) as per your relation. I have given scenario of one to many relation.

```
//In tblUser Model
public List<tblUserPermission> UserPermissionList {get;set;}

//In tblUserPermission model
public tblUser User {get;set;}
```

Sorry, models and first method are in C# code.